# (Odoo) How to download PDF reports from website?

Tags: controller, report, odoo

How can I download a pdf report (Odoo v14) from a controller on the website?

I tried solving the problem with the following code:

```
@http.route(['/my/projects/invoices/<int:invoice_id>/download'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def download_customer_project_report(self, invoice_id):

    invoice = request.env.ref('account.report_invoice_with_payments').sudo()._render_qweb_pdf([invoice_id])[0]
    pdf_http_headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf))]

    return request.make_response(invoice, headers=pdf_http_headers)
```

But i kept runnign into this error `AttributeError: 'ir.ui.view' object has no attribute '_render_qweb_pdf'`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with the following code:

```
@http.route(['/my/projects/invoices/<int:invoice_id>/download'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def download_pdf(self, invoice_id):
    invoice = request.env['account.move'].sudo().search([('id', '=', invoice_id)], limit=1)
    if not invoice or invoice.partner_id.id != request.env.user.partner_id.id:
        return None
    pdf, _ = request.env['ir.actions.report']._get_report_from_name(
        'account.report_invoice').sudo()._render_qweb_pdf(
        [int(invoice_id)])
    pdf_http_headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf)),
                        ('Content-Disposition', content_disposition('%s - Invoice.pdf' % (invoice.name)))]
    return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdf_http_headers)
```

Instead of ref, I used the method _get_report_from_name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [0] looks off to me at 4 line of your code. Can you remove it and try it again. For example:

```
@http.route(['/my/projects/invoices/<int:invoice_id>/download'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def download_customer_project_report(self, invoice_id):

    invoice = request.env.ref('account.report_invoice_with_payments').sudo()._render_qweb_pdf([invoice_id])
    pdf_http_headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf))]

    return request.make_response(invoice, headers=pdf_http_headers)
```

Comment: I tried, it did not work (still showing the same error). I even tried adding 'ir.actions.report' to env,
 
pdf = request.env['ir.actions.report'].ref('account.report_invoice').sudo()._render_qweb_pdf([int(invoice_id)]),

but I got the following error: 'ir.actions.report' object has no attribute 'ref'.